# How do I specify the folder in my project a package is installed to?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget, nuget-package

I'm using twitter bootstrap in my project and it installs 15 files into my project in the scripts folder.

```
project/scripts/bootstrap-alert.js
project/scripts/bootstrap-button.js
```

I can move these files into a folder but then when doing an upgrade it just installs everything at the /scripts level again.  This gets totally out of control when you add jquery, knockout etc etc

```
project/scripts/twitter.bootstrap/bootstrap-alert.js
project/scripts/twitter.bootstrap/bootstrap-button.js
```

I want to tell nuget to install the files to project/scripts/twitter.bootstrap within the project.

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly it's not supported, but there are suggestions about it on the nuget codeplex site.

http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/256542